# Node.js and Android prevent requests at the same time

Tags: android, node.js

Sorry for the title. I literally have no idea how can I describe my problem here. I have a **download_count** property in my Model. Every time a download from Android App successfully completed, it **GET**s the **download_count** and fires back a **PUT** request with a increased number.

So my problem is, it is highly possible that Device A GETS and before Device A sends back the increased number, Device B gets the same value.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a GET request to fetch the download_count? You don't need to do that to update the download count in your NodeJS backend. Instead, why don't you just fire a single POST request after completion of a download, and handle the updation of the count in the model in the route? So you don't have to worry about any latency issues.

Here is an idea of what I'm on about, assuming you are using MEAN Stack with MongooseJS: -

```
router.post('/update', (req, res)=>{

    user.findById(id, function (err, data) {   //Send some parameter in the POST request so as to uniquely identify whichever entry you wish to update the download_count of
          if (err) console.log(err);
    var new_download_count = data.download_count + 1;  //Updating count

    data.set({ download_count: new_download_count });  //Saving new count
    data.save(function (err, updatedData) {
          if (err) console.log(err);

          res.send(updatedTank);   //Indicate new object
    });
  }); 
 });
```

Comment: I havent tried your code yet, but it is an awesome logic.... Btw, why did you use POST instead of PUT?

Comment: Oh now I get it, because server handles everything, doh

Comment: Glad I could help